# scipy.stats.kstest with distributions other than norm

Tags: python, scipy

I have trouble using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in scipy (scipy.stats.kstest). the online doc  (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html) says it requires  the sample, the cdf for comparison with the option of just naming one of the scipy.stats distributions, the cdf arguments (and several optional values)

as long as the chosen cdf does not require any additional arguments, all appears fine

```
teststat,pval=stats.kstest(sample,'norm')
```

(where sample is a list of values.) 
However, with other distributions that require additional agruments, such as t, chisquared etc. it won't work for me. it protests correctly if no further arguments are given

```
teststat,pval=stats.kstest(sample,'t')

TypeError: _cdf() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

if an argument is given,

```
teststat,pval=stats.kstest(sample,'t',24)
```

it complains

```
TypeError: cdf() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Now I'm not exactly sure what that means but it seems that it wants not int, 24, but a sequence of one int, (24). However:

```
teststat,pval=stats.kstest(sample,'t',24)

TypeError: cdf() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Defining the distribution manually does not yield better results either because it does not feel that this is callable:

```
numargs = stats.t.numargs
[ df ] = [0.9,] * numargs
rv = stats.t(df)
teststat,pval=stats.kstest(sample,stats.t.cdf(numpy.linspace(0, numpy.minimum(rv.dist.b, 3)),df))

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

What do I do to make it work? (Google search for either the kstest function or the various error messages do not turn up anything useful to answer this question.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this error:

```
TypeError: cdf() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

makes me think that you're right, and it wants a sequence, not an integer.  The docs say

```
args : tuple, sequence
    distribution parameters, used if rvs or cdf are strings
```

Which seems to work:

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> sample = scipy.stats.t(1).rvs(size=10**6)
>>> scipy.stats.kstest(sample, 't', (1,))
(0.0006249662221899932, 0.82960203415652445)
```

or more explicitly:

```
>>> scipy.stats.kstest(sample, 't', args=(1,))
(0.0006249662221899932, 0.82960203415652445)
```

Comment: thanks DSM,

you are, of course, right. (x,) is the proper way to state a sequence; I was unfamiliar with that variable type. thanks.